# Where to put @EnableWebMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, software-design

Let's consider a Spring Boot application which has a web module (or several ones) as a dependency.

The application doesn't use any auto-configuration (for a reason) and the web module artifact is Spring-Boot-free.

In respect of such an application structure I would expect the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in the application code like:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyApplication { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
```

To have a central point of control.

If I put the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation into the web module code, this module could possibly have impact on the whole application - for instance, when the application brings its own web configuration `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` etc. The control would be bottom-to-top and the behavior would become unpredictable from the application point of view.

Nevertheless almost all examples put `@EnableWebMvc` on particular configuration classes. Even in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-enable) one can find code snippets like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    ...
```

What is the right place to put the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation according the best practices of software design?

Comment: I am a fan of placing them at the `@Configuration` class that makes the most sense in case of multiple configuration classes.  My colleagues disagree and like to place it on the SpringBoot starter class (annotated by @SpringBootConfiguration).  A point could be made that placing all annotations on the App class provides a central view, but I personally loathe seeing halve a page of annotations on a single class.

Comment: Putting all annotations on the main class makes it impossible to use sliced tests. Use one config class per slice at least. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config: *If you use a test annotation to test a more specific slice of your application, you should avoid adding configuration settings that are specific to a particular area on the main method’s application class.*